# Link URL data missing for some creatives in Facebook api

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We opened issue about link url data that missing for some creative in facebook api , and we received answer that there are two ways to create an ad creative and the second one seems to have been created using an existing post ID, to get the link to the second ad we should call to {post_id}?fields=call_to_action .
Is there a way to get call_to_action data for multiple post IDS?
I have searched in the docs and didn't find way to do so ..

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to get call_to_action data for multiple post IDS?

```
?ids=post_id_1,post_id_2,...&fields=call_to_action
```

You can request data for up to 50 objects in one go this way.